# Problems with sorting items in a simple jQuery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, slider

I've made a simple slider using html and jquery and it works perfectly fine when there is only one on page, but when adding more of them they kind of mix together. On page it looks like this:

```
<div class="shop3">
<ul class="shop-list">
<li class="shop-unit" style="background: url('#');">
<div class="shop-unit-overlay">
<div class="su">
<div class="su1">#</div>
<div class="su2">#</div>
<div class="su3"><a href="#">SHOP NOW</a></div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
<li class="shop-unit" style="background: url('#')">
<div class="shop-unit-overlay">
<div class="su">
<div class="su1">#</div>
<div class="su2">#</div>
<div class="su3"><a href="#">SHOP NOW</a></div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
<li class="shop-unit" style="background: url('#');">
<div class="shop-unit-overlay">
<div class="su">
<div class="su1">#</div>
<div class="su2">#</div>
<div class="su3"><a href="#">SHOP NOW</a></div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
<li class="shop-unit" style="background: url('#');">
<div class="shop-unit-overlay">
<div class="su">
<div class="su1">#</div>
<div class="su2">#</div>
<div class="su3"><a href="#">SHOP NOW</a></div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And the script:

```
$('.shop-klik').click(function(){
        $('.shop-list').animate({
            top: "-=228"
        }, 2000, function(){
            $('.shop-list').css('top', 0);
            $(".shop-list li:first-child").each(function(){
                $(this).appendTo($(this).parent());
            });
        }); 
    });
```

.shop-klik is a button outside this slider. The animation works fine, but there are problems with sorting elements. I kind of know why it doesn't work as I want it to (when there are two sliders it does appendTo twice, when there are three - thrice, etc.), but I really don't know how to force it to do it only once. My main goal is to restrict appendTo to act only once per click.

Comment: if you are sure that the problem is that appendTo is called twice why dont use a `flag` in closure?

Comment: I've figured it out, thanks for your help. It looks like this:

`var flag=true;
 
 $('.shop-klik').click(function(){
  flag = true;
  $('.shop-list').animate({
   top: "-=228"
  }, 500, function(){
   $('.shop-list').css('top', 0);
   if (flag){
    $(".shop-list li:first-child").each(function(){
     $(this).appendTo($(this).parent());
     flag = false;
    });
   }
  }); 
 });`

Answer (score 0):

This should work also, but faster:

```
var flag = true;
$('.shop-klik').click(function () {
    var $shopList = $(".shop-list");
    flag = true;

    $shopList.animate({top: "-=228"}, 500, function () {
        $shopList.css('top', 0);
        if (flag) {
            $shopList.find("li:first-child").each(function () {
                this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
                flag = false;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Try storing `jQuery objects` instead of creating identical ones (it's faster).

For many tasks (like `appending` one element to another) you can also use vanilla `JS` (which will usually be faster).